# AngularJS development environment-clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie in AngularJS and got stuck up on how to set up the angularJS for development.

[Link1](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute)

link1 says we need node.js and a series of other tools which have to be installed prior to use AngularJS.

But in W3school it says only a reference is enough to use this.

[link2](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/)

so what is the difference between the two links? which is right? Do i need to BUILD angularJS before use? (usually we wont build JS files)

Comment: You basically just need to reference AngularJS in your script section in html to use it. The first link is talking about building the angular source using node and other tools.

Comment: So can you share a scenario where the steps mentioned in link 1 has to be followed?

Comment: If you want to patch Angular, fix some Angular bug. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Difference:**

The First link (first part of first link) is more for the people want to build Angular themselves for some purposes: maybe they develop Angular or/and want to change something in Angular's code. *You do not need to build Angular*, because the ready java-scripts are available [here](https://angularjs.org/) in the download section and on any CDN you like.

From the first link you should pay attention to [Getting Started](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started) section.

The second link is for practical usage of Angular, it fits your requirements 100%.

**which is right:**

Both are :) but you need the second one, If you want to build an application with(using) angular.

**Do i need to BUILD angularJS before use:**

Hence you do not need to build angular, just link it to your project.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**Some extra info that I hope will hep you:**

*On Node.js for JS frontend Developers:*

Node.js is actually must have for good JS developer, a lot of build automation and dependency management tools in JS, like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [Bower](http://bower.io/) and others, are based on Node.js.

*Angular:*

Remember that angular is modular framework it is divided to a [lot of modules(libraries)](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/), each for certain purpose.

*On how to effectively learn Angular:*

To learn angular faster and write clear and maintainable angular.js srtucture I suggest you to:

1. Take a look at the [official tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), it's good to understand how they structure the project and how to use Angular modules.
2. For the beginning, use [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed): It is a ready skeleton of Angular.js application. Despite it looks pretty outdated it gives a proper feeling of where to put your directives, services, controllers and templates. Good structured program is a first step to write a maintainable code.
3. Spend a time reviewing other developers code, it will give you an understanding of how to write good and maintainable angular.js applications.
4. Use some good IDE: Netbeans, Webstorm, VisualStudio or Eclipse(I hope), I hope they all (I use Netbeans) have a good Angular.js support with builtin documentation that will help you during development.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Arutinyants.  this gives me an insight of how to deal with AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build AngularJS if you don't want to.  They are nice enough to build the files (which is really just a lot of concatenation) and host them on a CDN.  You can take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading which talks about where to get these pre-built files.

Comment: so i can conclude it as,unless otherwise host it as offline, a Google CDN URL can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Link 1 is about developing angular. Eg changing it, modify it.

Link 2 is about developing with it. Eg building a site.

So, I presume you want to make something with angular so link 2

What dev tools are you planning to use? My preference is visual studio but my background is .net .

You can just simply include the JS from the CDN or if you just want to experiment plunk or jsfiddle are both pretty good